# Com Tratar uma string transformando em um array

Tags: php

Recebo uma string do banco dessa forma:

```
POLYGON((-22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835, -22.88643210096987 -43.118324215556555, -22.886694032959 -43.117846782351904, -22.886763222456636 -43.11767512097496, -22.886782990878046 -43.117605383540564, -22.886886775043237 -43.11763757004875, -22.887133879879073 -43.11891966595787, -22.88630360584699 -43.11942392125267, -22.886115805063966 -43.118823106433325, -22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835))
```

Preciso somente das coordenadas entre os parenteses:

```
-22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835, -22.88643210096987 -43.118324215556555, -22.886694032959 -43.117846782351904, -22.886763222456636 -43.11767512097496, -22.886782990878046 -43.117605383540564, -22.886886775043237 -43.11763757004875, -22.887133879879073 -43.11891966595787, -22.88630360584699 -43.11942392125267, -22.886115805063966 -43.118823106433325, -22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835
```

Com as Coordenadas preciso criar uma array:

```
{lat: -22.886145457836463, lng: -43.118764097835},
{lat: -22.88643210096987, lng: -43.118324215556555},
{lat: -22.886694032959, lng: -43.117846782351904}
```

e etc...

Como faço?

Comment: Carlos eu não percebi que a sua pergunta é uma duplicata, não precisa criar várias pergunta para mesma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para extrair essas informações, precisa trabalhar com 3 funções que são [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) para remover aquilo que é desnecessário e depois utilizar [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) criando um [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) mediante os espaços entre os valores e com [trim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) para remover os espaços *iniciais* e *finais*.

Após isso crie um `for` de passo ***2*** e faça o novo [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) a partir desse tendo as chaves `lat` e `lng` como pedido na sua pergunta, ***exemplo minimo***:

```
<?php

$str = 'POLYGON((-22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835, -22.88643210096987
                -43.118324215556555, -22.886694032959 -43.117846782351904,
                -22.886763222456636 -43.11767512097496, -22.886782990878046
                -43.117605383540564, -22.886886775043237 -43.11763757004875,
                -22.887133879879073 -43.11891966595787, -22.88630360584699
                -43.11942392125267, -22.886115805063966 -43.118823106433325,
                -22.886145457836463 -43.118764097835))';

function array_final($str)
{
    $str = str_replace(['POLYGON','((','))'], [''], $str);
    $str = explode(" ", trim($str));
    $arrays = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i += 2)
    {
        $arrays[] = ['lat' => $str[$i], 'lng' => $str[$i+1]];
    }
    return $arrays;
}

var_dump(array_final($str));
```

[Exemplo ONLINE](https://ideone.com/eXtkXq)

<sup>***Observação:*** o Framework [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) que é escrito em [php](/questions/tagged/php), não vai resolver todos os problemas, principalmente os particulares, muitas vezes precisamos escovar código para que criar determinadas soluções, que é nesse caso em especifico.</sup>

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)
- [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)
- [trim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php)
- [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php)

Comment: Muito Obrigado meu amigo !!!

funcionou com var_dump(array_final($str));  agora como posso atribuir a uma variável pra passar pra view, pode me dar só mais essa ajudinha?

Desde já agradeço muito!!!!

Comment: Como @CarlosAlexandreRRamos não entendi?

Comment: Bom dia.

Estamos utilizando o var_dump para mostrar os resultados correto?

Quando tento isso por exemplo:
_$resultado = array_final($str);_
não funciona, porém preciso atribuir esse resultado a uma variável compreende?

Comment: O primeiro resultado do array traz:
`  0 => array:2 [▼
    "lat" => "[{"area":"-22.886145457836463"
    "lng" => "-43.118764097835,"
  ]`

Tem como remover esse **area:**

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos o exemplo da resposta tem uma função criada por mim com o nome de `array_final`, sabe aquele texto que você precisa tranformar naquele formato em `array` esse método faz isso, o var_dump é só para mostrar mas, o resultado do `array_final` é o que você precisa!

Comment: Muito Obrigado consegui, mais tem como tirar area do array?

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos tudo bem, seguinte, existe perguntas suas sem respostas, existem perguntas suas com resposta que você não interage, e cada pergunta feita ter algums respostas que solucionam o mesmo problema, agora você veio e fez uma sub pergunta, tirar área do `array`, não entendi talvez caiba uma nova pergunta que relacione essa, mas, tem uma coisa que o site ainda você não entendeu, existe uma troca aonde as boas respostas podem ser pontuadas e até aceita como solução do seu problema, e no seu usuário tem um monte em aberto, o pessoal começa a não responder a sua perguntas continua .

Comment: porque você não faz a sua parte, começe a repensar como deve se comportar e ajudar não só você, mas, todos que compreende aqui ... Pergunto: não é melhor abrir outro questionamento sobre a área retirada desse array? que tal ? @CarlosAlexandreRRamos

Comment: Desculpe Virgilio, mais não estou interagindo da maneira correta pois não sabia desses detalhes, porém acho que independente de qualquer coisa o intuito principal e nos ajudarmos mutuamente, de forma que vou me atentar para esse fato **só quero que entenda que não e maldade e só falta de conhecimento **

Comment: @CarlosAlexandreRRamos acredito sim que seja falta de conhecimento, por isso eu também estou te avisando e querendo que você usufrua da melhor maneira possível, e ajude a comunidade crescer, sobre a área faça uma pergunta é assim que funciona, cada duvida uma pergunta ... uma pergunta bem contextualizada é o que precisamos para te ajudar ...

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio.

o link da nova pergunta tem como retirar o área também por favor:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242789/tratamento-de-arrays/242816#242816