# Tratamento de Arrays

Tags: php

Galera estou recebendo um array:

```
[{lat: "[{"area":"-22.88975203013098", lng: "-43.12695211119432,"},…]
0
:
{lat: "[{"area":"-22.88975203013098", lng: "-43.12695211119432,"}
1
:
{lat: "-22.88977179811704", lng: "-43.12685018725176,"}
2
:
{lat: "-22.88979650809557", lng: "-43.126624881694504,"}
3
:
{lat: "-22.890513095516", lng: "-43.12649077124376,"}
4
:
{lat: "-22.89054274732773", lng: "-43.126807271907516,"}
5
:
{lat: "-22.88975203013098", lng: "-43.12695211119432"}]"}
```

Preciso retirar essa parte:

```
"[{"area":"`
```

como faço?

Comment: E aonde está `"area"` nesse código que você colocou ?

Comment: Isso é um json, use a função `json_decode()` para manipula-lo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é usar regex. Baseando no trecho que quer remover, seria usar o método  `preg_replace` para substituir o valor desejado por uma *string* vazia. O padrão seria:

```
$pattern = '/\"\[{"area":"/s';
```

Veja [funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/dz09Ye).

Veja aqui o [regex funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/IdsOkb/1).

E como bonus, veja abaixo com Javascript.

```js
str = '[{lat: "[{"area":"-22.88975203013098", lng: "-43.12695211119432,"},…] 0 : {lat: "[{"area":"-22.88975203013098", lng: "-43.12695211119432,"} 1 : {lat: "-22.88977179811704", lng: "-43.12685018725176,"} 2 : {lat: "-22.88979650809557", lng: "-43.126624881694504,"} 3 : {lat: "-22.890513095516", lng: "-43.12649077124376,"} 4 : {lat: "-22.89054274732773", lng: "-43.126807271907516,"} 5 : {lat: "-22.88975203013098", lng: "-43.12695211119432"}]"}';

console.log(str.replace(/\"\[{"area":"/g,''));
```

Comment: Como posso utilizar em conjunto com a função:
`       function array_final($str)
{
    $str = str_replace(['POLYGON','((','))'], [''], $str);
    $str = explode(" ", trim($str));
    $arrays = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i += 2)
    {
      $arrays[] = ['lat' => $str[$i], 'lng' => $str[$i+1]];
    }
    return $arrays;
  
}
`